# Error with multiple Vcenter connection in my powershell script

Tags: powershell, powercli, vcenter

I have a PowerShell script that needs to start a connection on two Vcenters. So the beginning of my script is:

```
Set-PowerCLIConfiguration -DefaultVIServerMode Multiple -Confirm:$false

Connect-VIServer -Server Vcenter1 -User XXXX -Password XXX

Connect-VIServer -Server Vcenter2 -User XXXX  -Password XXXX
```

Now, in my script I have a condition:

```
if(element find in Vcenter1){
Get-VM my_VM| New-TagAssignment -Tag XXXX -Server Vcenter1

}

elseif(element find in Vcenter2){
 Get-VM my_VM| New-TagAssignment -Tag XXXX -Server Vcenter2
}
```

But my script return this error:

```
New-TagAssignment 
The TagCisImp - 'my_tag' must be managed by the same VC Server that you are using to invoke this operation
```

I don't understand why I am getting this error, even if I set the `ServerMode` to `multiple` and with each `-Server` parameters...

Can someone tell me what is wrong with my script?

Comment: I would rejig the code to connect and disconnecting getting what you need out of each vcenter and then compare. Even on command line I have issues when connected to two vcenters.

Comment: Finally, I cut the two connections to the Vcenter and Then I initate a new one in my condition.